# Is it a possible to call a lambda in different account from the cloudformation one?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, policy

I have a lambda on one account with this policy attached:

```
{
  "Sid": "Id-123",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::115333656057:root"},
  "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:260143830488:function:CentralInstanceScheduler-InstanceSchedulerMain"
}
```

When I create a stack from account 115333656057 with my user trying to execute the lambda I got this error:

```
  User: arn:aws:iam::115333656057:user/uguesm is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:260143830488:function:CentralizedInstanceScheduler-InstanceSchedulerMain
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Account 260143830488 - Edit your Role to add the policy to InvokeFunction and a trust policy for another account.

Permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:260143830488:function:CentralInstanceScheduler-InstanceSchedulerMain"
    },
  ]
}
```

Trust Relationship Policy:

```
{
  "Sid": "Id-123",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": { "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::115333656057:role/<lambda-role>"},
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
}
```

In Account 115333656057 - Create a lambda execution role to AssumeRole

Permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::260143830488:role/<RoleName>"
  }
}
```

Trust Relationship policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"},
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
  }
}
```

Comment: I created all the described resources but I omitted some details. The lambda fuction is trigger from account 115333656057 by CloudFormation on an aws CustomResource ```"Resources": {
      "OfficehoursSwitzerland": {
        "Type": "Custom::ServiceInstanceSchedule",
        "Properties": {          
          "ServiceToken": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:260143830488:function:CentralInstanceScheduler"
            , ``` It seems that I cannot assign the correct role to that resource like I usually do with InstanceProfile to ec2 instances....

Comment: I guess you are not setting role when you create stack? Are you sure passing the role when you create the stack? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-add-tags.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a [Lambda resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html). This is a policy that exists directly on the Lambda. Doing it with a resource-based policy avoids needing to create additional roles and using STS::AssumeRole.

In CDK, it looks like this:

```
        account = 123456789012
        lambda_.CfnPermission(
            scope,
            f"XAccountInvocation{account}",
            action="lambda:InvokeFunction",
            function_name=handler.function_name,
            principal=f"arn:aws:iam::{account}:root",
        )
```

Comment: This is the right way. No floating role, resource scoped rights